# Why my Angular JS app is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, debugging

Here is `firstAngularJSApp.html`

```
<html ng-app="store"><!-- "ng-app" creates and angular app by running the module. because of ng-app html inside of this tag will be treated as part of angular app --> 
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"/>
</head>
<body>

<p>I am {{ 4+6 }}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is **app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('store',[]);
```

When I load the page I don't get "I am 10" rather it's blank page. But when I open the source code using `Ctrl+U` I can see `"<p>I am {{ 4+6 }}</p>"`

[image]

**I am using XAMMP to access my files.**

Comment: Path is correct, self closing script tag was causing problem as mentioned by @Tushar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the self-closing `script` tag which will not work. See [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

So, your app.js file is not included on the page and your angular app is not bootstrapped.

Use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Also, make sure the file paths are correct.

Answer (score 0):

seems like your angular framework is not loaded to the page. make sure it is loaded correctly and check the paths. if you want you can use the network tab in developer tools to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Your **app.js** will not load by this method of self closing tags because it is usually **intended to contain some piece of code inside it**. This **prevents your module from being loaded** hence your angular app is not working.

use

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

All the best!!!